# why java polymorphism not work in my example

Tags: java, polymorphism, subclass, superclass

I have these 4 java clases:
1

```
public class Rect {
    double width;
    double height;
    String color;

    public Rect( ) {
        width=0;
        height=0;
        color="transparent";      
    }

    public Rect( double w,double h) {
        width=w;
        height=h;
        color="transparent";
    }

    double area()
    {
        return  width*height;
    } 
}
```

2

```
public class PRect extends Rect{
    double depth;

    public PRect(double w, double h ,double d) {
        width=w;
        height=h;
        depth=d;
    }

    double area()
    {
        return  width*height*depth;
    }     
}
```

3

```
public class CRect extends Rect{ 
    String color;

    public CRect(double w, double h ,String c) {
        width=w;
        height=h;
        color=c;
    }

    double area()
    {
        return  width*height;
    }     
}
```

4

```
public class test {

    public test() { }

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Rect r1=new Rect(2,3);
        System.out.println("area of r1="+r1.area());

        PRect pr1=new PRect(2,3,4);
        System.out.println("area of pr1="+pr1.area());


        CRect cr1=new CRect(2,3,"RED");
        System.out.println("area of cr1="+cr1.area()+"  color = "+cr1.color);


        System.out.println("\n POLY_MORPHISM ");
        Rect r2=new Rect(1,2);
        System.out.println("area of r2="+r2.area());

        Rect pr2=new PRect(1,2,4);
        System.out.println("area of pr2="+pr2.area());


        Rect cr2=new CRect(1,2,"Blue");
        System.out.println("area of cr2="+cr2.area()+"  color = "+cr2.color); 

    }
}
```

***I got the output:***

```
area of r1=6.0
area of pr1=24.0
area of cr1=6.0  color = RED
POLY_MORPHISM 
area of r2=2.0
area of pr2=8.0
area of cr2=2.0  color = transparent***
```

**why consider cr2 as Rect(super class) and with "transparent" color not as  CRect (sub class) with "Blue" color ?**

Comment: You need a `getColor()` method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is one of the problems of using visible fields - you end up using them...

You've got a `color` field in both `Rect` and `CRect`. Fields are *not* polymorphic, so when you use `cr2.color`, that uses the field declared in `Rect`, which is *always* set to `"transparent"`.

Your `CRect` class should *not* have its own `color` field - it should supply the colour to the superclass constructor. It makes no sense for a single rectangle to have two different `color` fields - it could have `borderColor` and `fillColor`, of course - but just `color` is too ambiguous...

Comment: or instance variables are not overridden but they are visible in your subclass's

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR: I'm not sure I understand your comment, but the idea of overriding a field is simply not applicable, as there's no polymorphism over fields...

Comment: yes, `polymorphism doesn't apply to fields(instance variables)`, doesn't that mean, they can't be overridden ??

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR: Yes, they can't be overridden, because polymorphism simply doesn't apply. It doesn't apply to static variables either, which are also fields.

Comment: thats what my first comment implied, :P

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR: Not really. Your first comment basically didn't make sense - hence *my* first comment. I was trying to clarify what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

You should include an explicit `super()` call in your subclasses' constructors:

```
public CRect(double w, double h ,String c) {
    super(w, h);
    width=w;
    height=h;
    color=c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cr2.area()` will call `CRect.area()` but `cr2.color` will use the field `Rect.color`. You should use the function style getArea() and have `CRect.getColor() { return color; }` as well as `Rect.getColor() { return color; }`