# Java Inheritance Puzzle

Tags: java, inheritance

I have created the following puzzle for inheritance in Java:

**Animal.java**

```
public class Animal {
    private String sound;

    public void roar() {
        System.out.println(sound);
    }

    public void setSound(String sound) {
        this.sound = sound;
    }
}
```

**Tiger.java**

```
public class Tiger extends Animal {
    public String sound;

    public Tiger() {
        sound = "ROAR";
    }
}
```

**Jungle.java**

```
public class Jungle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tiger diego = new Tiger();

        diego.roar();
        diego.sound = "Hust hust";
        diego.roar();
        diego.setSound("bla");
        diego.roar();
        System.out.println(diego.sound);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
null
null
bla
Hust hust
```

I guess this weird behaviour is taking place, because `sound` in Animal is private while `sound` in Tiger is public. But can you explain (and tell me the relevant parts of the JLS) why this happens?

Comment: You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685300/is-there-a-way-to-override-class-variables-in-java

Comment: Section [8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3) in the JLS talks about field hiding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fields are not polymorphic, methods are polymorphic.

```
 diego.roar();
```

calls `roar()` method in `Animal` and prints `sound` from `Animal`.

```
diego.sound = "Hust hust";
```

Sets sound value in `Tiger` class `sound` variable

```
diego.roar();
```

returns null; because prints sound from Animal, which is still null. Above sound assignment reflects on Tiger class variable, not Animal class.

diego.setSound("bla");

sets `Animal` sound to `bla`

```
diego.roar();
```

prints `bla` because setSound update sound variable of Animal class with `bla`.

System.out.println(diego.sound);

prints `Hust hust` due to the fact that diego is of type `Tiger` and you have accessed field sound of `Tiger` and fields are not polymorphic.

Please refer [java language specification 8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3) for more details.

Comment: I'm not sure if I really understood this: "update sound variable of Animal class": So my Object of the type Tiger has variables of the type Tiger and Animal? How can/do I access the variables of the Type Animal inside of Tiger?: Ah, just found it: super.Sound

Answer (score 2):

You can override functions in Java, not variables.

Remove the line `public String sound;` from `Tiger.java`

and either:

- Declare `String sound` as `protected` or `public` in `Animal.java`, or
- Define a `setSound()` function for `Animal.java` for controlled access to member variables (i.e. `sound`)

For a fuller explanation, see [Jon Skeet's excellent answer to an almost identical problem yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748124/why-java-polymorphism-not-work-in-my-example/).

Comment: If you remove the public sound then Tiger won't compile.

Comment: Remove the public shadowing `sound` *and* utilize `setSound()`.

Comment: @HotLicks oops, missed the private part

Comment: You've always got to look out for your private parts.

Comment: @HotLicks haha ;) this reminds me of the time when my favorite C++ teacher said in class: "We always bare our privates to our friends."

Comment: ("but never to the children of our friends!")

Answer (score 2):

As other have already noted: Fields are not subject to polymorphism.

My new twist to this is: Access to fields is decided *statically* at compile time, not *dynamically* at runtime. So here

```
Tiger diego = new Tiger();
diego.sound = "Hust hust";
```

the variable `diego` has the static type `Tiger`. So the compiler will generate an access to `Tiger.sound`. But in contrast (if `Animal.sound` would not be `private`) :

```
Animal diego = new Tiger();
diego.sound = "Hust hust";
```

the compiler will generate an access to `Animal.sound`. This can be also forced by casting:

```
Tiger diego = new Tiger();
((Animal)diego).sound = "Hust hust";
```

With this in mind you can go through your puzzle and for each access to any `sound` field you can tell the static type either of the implicit `this` or of `diego` at that point. Then you also know which of both fields is actually accessed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to recognize the `Animal.sound` is not the same field as `Tiger.sound`.  You in fact have two different fields, that can have two different values, and are set in two different ways.

`Animal.setSound()` updates the value of `Animal.sound`, does not update the value of `Tiger.sound`.

`diego.sound = "Hust hust"` updates the value of `Tiger.sound`, not the value of `Animal.sound`.

See the section [What you can do in a subclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) in the [Inheritance Turorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Comment: Although this answer is correct, exctly what I was expecting for this question. But also, I would be more interested if you add some more technical terms into it, as to why is this behaviour? Why `diego.sound` refers to `Tiger.sound`, so that it can clarify the doubts of OP.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `Tiger` class to:

```
public class Tiger extends Animal {

    public Tiger() {
        setSound("ROAR");
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `roar()` method defined in `Animal` uses the member private field `sound` defined in the very same `Animal` class.

The `sound` from `Animal` isn't visible to the `Tiger` class, because it's private. So you declared a new `sound` field for the `Tiger` subclass, but that didn't override the original one from `Animal`. The `Animal` class still uses it's own version of `sound`, because it's the only version it sees. **Unlike methods, field can't be overriden**.

One solution is to use getter/setter methods declared in the base class (`Animal`) for all access to properties, even from the subclasses.

---

Another possible solution would be using **abstract** methods and polymorphism:

You don't implement sound method in the Animal base class, you just declare an abstract method and force subclasses to provide their own implementations:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public void roar() {
        System.out.println(sound());
    }

    public abstract String sound();
}

public class Tiger extends Animal {
    public String sound() {
        return "ROAR";
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    public String sound() {
        return "HOOF HOOF";
    }
}
```

Even though there is no implementation (no body with code) of the `sound()` method in Animal, it is still possible to call that method from other methods of this class, such as `roar()`.

Of course, this approach makes you unable to change the sound of an existing animal object (there is no setter), making animals **immutable**, which might seem inconvenient at first, but if you think about it for a while, you might find out that in many cases, you do not actually need to change state of the objects in this manner.

Using *immutable* objects is actually convenient, because the code is more simple and secure, because you don't have to think about all the possible states that can possible occur during the execution of the program.

Comment: This doesn't help. I want an *explanation*, not a fix. I made this error by intention (to learn).

Comment: @moose It took some time to write an explanation. :)

Comment: Even if the sound was public or protected in Animal, the same problem would occur.

Answer (score 0):

system out statements (1) and (2) are referring to the instance variable sound of superclass which is not inherited as instance/class variables are not inherited in java and you havent set super variable. (3), the super variable is set via calling the inherited method.(4) is set when you did a direct assignment.

Comment: @CodeDreamer I believe instance/class variables can be inherited, depending on the modifier(public, private,  protected, default) used. In this particular instance you are correct, but it reads like you mean in all cases. See [Controlling Access to Member of Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Comment: Hi I mean to say that polymorphism are only for methods and not for fields. You are referring to the visibility of the fields. That is correct. But what I am referring to is what happens when both the super class and subclass have same variables. Then there is no polymorphism, rather the variable referred is that of the Compile time class and not runtime class. That was my point as well.