# Why does Java bind variables at compile time?

Tags: java, inheritance, jls

Consider the following example code

```
class MyClass {
    public String var = "base";

    public void printVar() {
        System.out.println(var);
    }
}

class MyDerivedClass extends MyClass {
    public String var = "derived";

    public void printVar() {
        System.out.println(var);
    }
}

public class Binding {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass base = new MyClass();
        MyClass derived = new MyDerivedClass();

        System.out.println(base.var);
        System.out.println(derived.var);
        base.printVar();
        derived.printVar();
    }
}
```

it gives the following output

```
base
base
base
derived
```

Method calls are resolved at runtime and the correct overridden method is called, as expected.
The variables access is instead resolved at compile time as I later learned.
I was expecting an output as

```
base
derived
base
derived
```

because in the derived class the re-definition of `var` shadows the one in the base class.
Why does the binding of variables happens at compile time and not at runtime? Is this only for performance reasons?

Comment: A side note for a similar language: in C# you'll have compile time binding in all cases, unless you specifically use `virtual` and `override`. And you can't use them for variables.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748124/why-java-polymorphism-not-work-in-my-example

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The reason is explained in the Java Language Specification in an example in [Section 15.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11), quoted below:

> ...
>
> *The last line shows that, indeed, the field that is accessed does not depend on the run-time class of the referenced object; even if `s` holds a reference to an object of class `T`, the expression `s.x` refers to the `x` field of class `S`, because the type of the expression `s` is `S`. Objects of class T contain two fields named `x`, one for class `T` and one for its superclass `S`.*
>
> ***This lack of dynamic lookup for field accesses allows programs to be run efficiently with straightforward implementations. The power of late binding and overriding is available, but only when instance methods are used**...*

So yes performance is a reason. The specification of how the field access expression is evaluated is stated as follows:

> - If the field is not `static`:
>
>   ...
>
>   - If the field is a non-blank `final`, then the result is the value of the named member field in type `T` found in the object referenced by the value of the *Primary*.

where *Primary* in your case refers the variable `derived` which is of type `MyClass`.

Another reason, as @Clashsoft suggested, is that in subclasses, fields are not overriden, they are *hidden*. So it makes sense to allow which fields to access based on the declared type or using a cast. This is also true for static methods. This is why the field is determined based on the declared type. Unlike overriding by instance methods where it depends on the actual type. The JLS quote above indeed mentions this reason implicitly:

> **The power of late binding and overriding is available, but only when instance methods are used.**

Answer (score 25):

While you might be right about performance, there is another reason why fields are not dynamically dispatched: You wouldn't be able to access the `MyClass.var` field at all if you had a `MyDerivedClass` instance.

Generally, I don't know about any statically typed language that actually has dynamic variable resolution. But if you really need it, you can make getters or accessor methods (which should be done in most cases to avoid `public` fields, anyway):

```
class MyClass
{
    private String var = "base";

    public String getVar() // or simply 'var()'
    {
        return this.var;
    }
}

class MyDerivedClass extends MyClass {
    private String var = "derived";

    @Override
    public String getVar() {
        return this.var;
    }
}
```

Comment: Much better than my answer would have been: Because the language was designed that way.

Comment: "You wouldn't be able to access the MyClass.var field at all if you had a MyDerivedClass instance." The same is true for methods, so this isn't really a reason at all.

Comment: @JensSchauder true, but for methods you always know that you override the other method, and that is *the* most well-known key feature of OO.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand your definition of "dynamic variable resolution", I can think of many languages that have it - dynamic languages such as Python or JavaScript typically resolve variables at runtime, and even Scala (a static language) looks up variables polymorphically.

Comment: I edited to include statically typed languages only. Scala depends on the JVM and sort of 'cheats' this by generating accessor method for fields. I don't know if that override behavior is intended by their compiler developers.

Comment: The `MyDerivedClass.var` could have a different type, too. In order to make the dynamic access possible, the language designers need to ensure type safety, so there should be a kind of _variable override_ or something like that, like it's done for virtual methods.

Answer (score 5):

The polymorphic behaviour of the java language works with methods and not member variables: they designed the language to bind member variables at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

In java, this is by design.
Because, the set up of fields to be dynamically resolved would make things to run a bit slower. And in real, there's not any reason of doing so.
Since, you can make your fields in any class **private** and access them with **methods** which are **dynamically resolved**.

So, fields are made to resolved better at **compile time** instead :)