# Shadowing / Scope of Variables

Tags: java, dynamic, static, shadowing

I thought I understood the concept of shadowing. But this Code made me wonder:

```
public class Counter {
int count = 0;

public void inc() {
    count++;
}

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}
```

}

```
class StepCounter extends Counter {
int count = 0;
int step = 1;

public StepCounter(int step) {
    this.step = step;
}

public void inc() {
    count += step;
}
```

}

```
StepCounter sc = new StepCounter(2);
    sc.inc();
    sc.inc();
    System.out.println(sc.getCount());
    System.out.println(sc.count);
```

So basically the Static Type of sc is `StepCounter`.
It's counter is incremented twice, so it's at 4 after the first two commands.
My count Variable is not a private one, it is package private (since I haven't declared any visibility on it).
So if I call the `.getCount()` method on sc, it first looks for it in StepCounter. There is none, so it goes to Counter. Here it finds the `getCount()` method.
that method returns count. If count had been static or private, I'd understand why it returns 0. But why does it return 0 in this case? Even if I made the variable count public in `StepCounter`, the result would still be 0.

Comment: Because member variables are not polymorphic.  Counter.getCount always returns Counter.count.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32422923/why-does-java-bind-variables-at-compile-time

Comment: Also the field here is not shadowed. It's hidden.

Comment: I'm still having a hard time, in the "related" answer it is easy too see b/c the methods are static. In mine, they are not. 
Are you saying that member variables (variables created inside the scope of a class) are always static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always avoid shadowing as much as possible, it could introduce serious unpredictable behaviours for your code.
What you're missing here is the concept of variable scoping in Java. `count` is merely a shorthand for `this.count`. So, given your code what the resolver does here, after the invocation of the `getCounter()` method, is:

1. Try to resolve `getCounter()` as an instance of `StepCounter` class
2. Fails, try to find any class ancestors
3. Nearest ancestor is `Counter`, so the context is switched over `Counter` class
4. Try to resolve `getCounter()` in `Counter` class
5. Method found, try to resolve the value of `count`
6. `getCounter()` is non-static, so  `count` is actually `this.count` (if `getCounter()` were to be static it would be `Counter.count`)
7. `this.count` resolves to value `0` in the scope of the instance of `Counter` class
8. `0` is returned

Comment: this outside the scope of a constructor refers to the current object, right?
So this.getClass() is StepCounter, so I still have problems figuering out step 7..

Comment: `getClass()` gives you the reference for the class on which your instance was constructed. In your example you have two separate values for `count` property in the `sc` instance you created. One in the context of `StepCounter` class and one in the context of `Counter` class. You can try that yourself just by adding this line at the end of your code: `System.out.println(((Counter) sc).count);`. `this` in the scope of `getCounter()` method takes the value of `(Counter) this`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So whenever I write this as an objecte reference, it is equal to writing (Cast of class I am writing this in) this.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

`getCount()` *can* only access the field `counter` tht was defined in the parent class. This class is resolved at *compile* time of the parent class. There is no *copy* of the method `getCounter()` in the child.

In the child class, you can use

```
Counter.this.count
```

to access the parent counter. But to avoid bad surprises, you should never name a field in such a ambiguous way.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, fields can't be overridden. Only methods can be overriden. So having a 'count' variable in StepCounter doesn't override the 'count' field in the super class 'Counter'. It just creates another field. However 'getCount' method returns the value of the 'count' field in the superclass. To have the desired functionality need to override the 'getCount' method in the StepCounter class.

Comment: My Object has the dynamic type Counter. Now the getCount() method says "return your field called count". Shouldn't it look in its own scope (B) first?

Comment: @InDaPond fields can never be overridden so when getCount method is executed it sees 'count' field defined in super class only