# Static methods & inheritance – java.lang.IllegalAccessError not found at compile-time

Tags: java, inheritance, static-methods

I have file structure and code like this:

../inside/A.java

```
package inside;
public class A{protected static void someStaticMethod(){}}
```

../inside/B.java

```
package inside;
import inside.A;
public class B extends A{protected static void someStaticMethod(){}}
```

../inside/C.java

```
package inside;
import inside.B;
public class C extends B{protected static void someStaticMethod(){}}
```

../Z.java

```
import inside.*;
class Z extends B{
  public static void main(String args[]){
  A.someStaticMethod();
  B.someStaticMethod();
  C.someStaticMethod(); // Fine at compile-time but IllegalAccessError at run-time.
}
```

}

At line with comment there is no error at compile-time but at runtime there is IllegalAccesError.

What is the true reason for this behavior?

I have found a question – [Why does Java bind variables at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32422923/why-does-java-bind-variables-at-compile-time) – where in the first answer there is maybe mentioned the reason but I am definitely not sure it is.

Comment: Does only the last line throw error?

Comment: Yes, only the last line does throw error.

Comment: What Java version is that?

Comment: I do not know from which version it comes but I am using Java 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably bug in javac – see http://www.coderanch.com/t/664583/java/java/Static-methods-inheritance-java-lang.

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown because you've set the visibility of the methods to `protected`, this means the methods can only be accessed from a sub class or in the same package.

So the reason why the `IllegalAccessError` is thrown is because your class `Z` isn't a sub class from `C` nor is `Z` in the same package as `C`.

Eclipse gives me a complier error:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>       The method doSomething() from the type C is not visible"

Comment: I know what is the reason for this error but I want to know **why the error is not found and compile-time** (unless I am using javac from cmd to compile Z.java).

Comment: oh sorry, I missunderstood your question. Then I can't help you. As shown in my answer eclipse gives me a complie time error with exact the same code so I don't know why it isn't working for you.

Comment: That quite funny because in NetBeans there is no error till run-time.

Comment: @Dimitros Begnis Can you please removal you answer so this unhelpful question can be removed?